# How to share config between Vim and Neovim

Tags: vimrc, neovim

I started using Neovim and moved my `.vimrc` to `.config/nvim/init.vim` and other stuff is located in `.local/share/nvim`.

What is the best way to share configs or even plugins between Vim and Neovim?
Symlinks? Can I change the directories in the .vimrc to use only one symlink?

After migrating my vim config to Neovim's default location, this seems to work almost:

```
ln -s ~/.local/share/nvim/site ~/.vim 
ln -s .config/nvim/init.vim .vimrc
```

Some plugins (using using [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug)) don't seem to work correctly. I can't load custom colorschmes nor vim-airline.

Comment: you can use `if has('nvim')` for nvim only commands

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Having your config in Neovim's default location, do the following:

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/nvim/site
ln -s ~/.local/share/nvim/site ~/.vim 
ln -s .config/nvim/init.vim .vimrc
```

To fix the colorscheme I [had to set to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10778126/859591) [256 terminal color mode](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/256_colors_in_vim), i.e. add this to your .vimrc (= init.vim) file, which [will be ignored by nvim](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/FAQ#colors-arent-displayed-correctly):

```
set t_Co=256  " Note: Neovim ignores t_Co and other terminal codes.
```

To get vim-airline I [added the following snippet](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline/wiki/FAQ#vim-airline-doesnt-appear-until-i-create-a-new-split) to .vimrc:

```
set laststatus=2
```

I don't quite understand why this is necessary only in vim and not in Neovim, but I am not [the](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline/issues/130) [only](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline/issues/334) [one](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline/issues/20) stumbling upon this thing.

Comment: This has always been necessary in vim. Probably nvim sets this as default and that's why it is working there.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt yes, of course you [are](https://neovim.io/doc/user/vim_diff.html) right.

Comment: I reckon commonly people will have **`~/.vimrc`** located in the home folder, as the previous line pointing to `~/.vim`.

Comment: Better to follow [the other answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/15548/5076), so that one can have nvim specific config, meanwhile sourcing `~/.vimrc` as shared config.

Comment: While Neovim ignores `t_xx` options, I'd argue that it's more correct to wrap something like that with `if !has('nvim')`, such as in [this example](https://neovim.io/doc/user/nvim.html#nvim-from-vim). It may ignore them now, but what if that changes in the future? It also implicitly indicates that the option  is related to Vim only.

Comment: As of 2022-07-13 nvim installs the plugins under ~/.local/share/nvim/plugged. Might as well ln -s ~/.vim/plugged ~/.local/share/nvim as well to avoid unnecessary reinstalls.

Answer (score 161):

**TL;DR**

You can use your existing `~/.vimrc`, files, and plugins located within `~/.vim` without having to symlink the files.

And this is now documented in NeoVim manual, see [Transitioning from Vim](https://neovim.io/doc/user/nvim.html#nvim-from-vim).

---

For Linux and macOS, just add below lines to the top of your `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`, or `%LOCALAPPDATA%\nvim\init.vim` for Windows.

```
set runtimepath^=~/.vim runtimepath+=~/.vim/after
let &packpath=&runtimepath
source ~/.vimrc
```

The above lines will add the existing paths and `~/.vimrc` file to your nvim setup.

Credit goes to  [vimcast 71 : Meet Neovim](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/meet-neovim/)

Comment: For anyone finding this and receiving the error because you're using an init.lua file, the lua code is:

`vim.cmd('set runtimepath^=~/.vim runtimepath+=~/.vim/after')`
`vim.o.packpath = vim.o.runtimepath`
`vim.cmd('source ~/.vimrc')`

Answer (score 26):

You can use `if has('nvim')`. Here are complete examples:

**Configuration only for Neovim:**

```
if has('nvim')
        tnoremap <Esc> <C-\><C-n>
endif
```

**Configuration only for Vim**

```
if !has('nvim')
    set ttymouse=xterm2
endif
```

Answer (score 7):

## Using `init.lua`

If you prefer to use `init.lua` instead of `init.vim`, you can put this code in `~/.config/nvim/init.lua`:

```lua
vim.cmd([[
set runtimepath^=~/.vim runtimepath+=~/.vim/after
let &packpath = &runtimepath
source ~/.vimrc
]])
```

### Explanation of this code:

you can run VimScript from Lua by running `vim.cmd(string)`. We want to use a multi-line string literal in the passed argument to `vim.cmd`, so we use Lua's syntax for multi-line string literals, which is opened by `[[` and closed by `]]`. In that multi-line string line, we run this Vimscript, as [recommended by the docs](https://neovim.io/doc/user/nvim.html#nvim-from-vim) for those transitioning from Vim:

- Add `~./vim` and `~/.vim/after` to the list of directories to search for runtime files like `filetype.vim`, `scripts.vim`, etc:

  ```
  set runtimepath^=~/.vim runtimepath+=~/.vim/after
  ```
- Add the full runtime path to the list of directories to use to find Vim packages:

  ```
  let &packpath = &runtimepath
  ```
- Load `~/.vimrc` configuration:

  ```
  source ~/.vimrc
  ```

Answer (score 5):

The method here tries to symlink `~/.config/nvim` to `~/.vim`, and make the conf compatible with `vim`.

```
# nvim conf dir: ~/.config/nvim
# vim conf dir: ~/.vim
# link the 1st as the 2nd with relative links

# Prepare a vimrc file in ~/.config/nvim folder
ln -sf ./init.vim ~/.config/nvim/vimrc

# Link the whole ~/.config/nvim folder as ~/.vim foler
ln -sf ./.config/nvim ~/.vim
```

After this setup, `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` is the real file used as conf. `~/.vim/vimrc` is just a link to it.

Now we need to make `vim` reuse `nvim`'s plugin manager, plugins, by changing `runtimepath` and `packpath`. In fact, the plugin paths are reused automatically, the following fix is reusing the plugin manger.

```
let g:is_nvim = has('nvim')
let g:is_vim8 = v:version >= 800 ? 1 : 0

" Reuse nvim's runtimepath and packpath in vim
if !g:is_nvim && g:is_vim8
  set runtimepath-=~/.vim
    \ runtimepath^=~/.local/share/nvim/site runtimepath^=~/.vim 
    \ runtimepath-=~/.vim/after
    \ runtimepath+=~/.local/share/nvim/site/after runtimepath+=~/.vim/after
  let &packpath = &runtimepath
endif
```

Source: [Share confs between vim and nvim](https://gist.github.com/9013f948345212563ede9c9ee56c6b42)

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to ipatch answer, which is the correct answer, if you have a slightly different setup from Vim you might need to adapt the path.

For example, on Windows, rather than using the default configuration with:

```
$HOME
   +--.vimrc
   +--.vim
```

I am using:

```
$HOME
   +--vimfiles
          +--vimrc
```

(The reasons is that is it easier to put a single directory under revision control than a file and a directory, particularly when the file is at the root of your home directory)

The following works for me then:

```
set runtimepath^=~/vimfiles runtimepath+=~/vimfiles/after
let &packpath=&runtimepath
source ~/vimfiles/vimrc
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to share `~/.vimrc` between vim and neovim without a neovim config file you can define `$VIMINIT` in your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` file:

```
export VIMINIT='let $MYVIMRC="$HOME/.vimrc" | source $MYVIMRC'
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following:

```
VIMINIT='if has("nvim")|let f="init.lua"|else|let f="vimrc"|end|let $MYVIMRC="~/.config/vim/".f|source $MYVIMRC'
```

Then put all files in `~/.config/vim`, and symlink `~/.config/nvim` to it.